# Eclipse error: Resource '/project-name' does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

There's a single project in one of my working sets that completely broke my Eclipse. I can't refresh it, I can't close it, I can't delete it. Usually, the way I fix other projects is by deleting them in Eclipse and reimporting them. I can't do that for this one. Because of that, I can't use this working set, there's walls of error everytime there's a SVN status cache refresh.

I don't know where the resource should be, where Eclipse is looking for it. The `project-name` folder does exist in `\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\`. Where else should I look?

In the error log, there are tons of `Resource '/project-name' does not exist.` errors. Same message, different stack trace depending on the call. An example:

```
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException(/project-name)[368]: java.lang.Exception: Resource '/project-name' does not exist.
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException.provideStackTrace(ResourceException.java:39)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException.<init>(ResourceException.java:35)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.checkExists(Resource.java:327)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.checkAccessible(Resource.java:201)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.checkAccessible(Project.java:142)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.getDescription(Project.java:394)
   at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.ValidationRegistryReader.getValidatorMetaData(ValidationRegistryReader.java:817)
   at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.ValidationRegistryReader.getValidatorMetaData(ValidationRegistryReader.java:795)
   at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.ValidationRegistryReader.isConfiguredOnProject(ValidationRegistryReader.java:1053)
   at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.ProjectConfiguration.extractProjectValidators(ProjectConfiguration.java:259)
   at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.ProjectConfiguration.getValidators(ProjectConfiguration.java:145)
   at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.EventManager.closing(EventManager.java:96)
   at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.EventManager.resourceChanged(EventManager.java:248)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$1.run(NotificationManager.java:297)
   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:287)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.handleEvent(NotificationManager.java:251)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.broadcastEvent(Workspace.java:371)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.close(Project.java:190)
   at org.eclipse.ui.actions.CloseResourceAction.invokeOperation(CloseResourceAction.java:168)
   at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceAction.execute(WorkspaceAction.java:156)
   at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceAction$1.runInWorkspace(WorkspaceAction.java:456)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:39)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:60)
```

When I try to close the project, I get this nullPointerException:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Close Project".

java.lang.NullPointerException
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalGetActiveBuildConfig(Project.java:752)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.getActiveBuildConfig(Project.java:349)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.getTreesToSave(SaveManager.java:1879)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.writeTree(SaveManager.java:2030)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.writeTree(SaveManager.java:2075)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.save(SaveManager.java:1216)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.save(SaveManager.java:1145)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.close(Project.java:194)
   at org.eclipse.ui.actions.CloseResourceAction.invokeOperation(CloseResourceAction.java:168)
   at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceAction.execute(WorkspaceAction.java:156)
   at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceAction$1.runInWorkspace(WorkspaceAction.java:456)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:39)
   at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:60)
```

How can I fix this?

*(I use `project-name` in lieu of the actual project name.)*

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, might there be some handles alive? The error seems to indicate eclipse's not  able to flush the closing-project change - if possible you could maybe try shutting the jvm instances.

If you didn't already, try to remove project from the working set(configure working sets -> edit) /remove the working set and create again without the plugin.

When importing - do you copy the project to the workspace or leave in the original place? I know you have already imported the project so it's just a thought for future I found myself useful :)